# Sane bluetooth keyboard setup for lightweight Linux desktop?

Tags: linux, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a pretty light Debian unstable setup, just xdm and a window manager, no fancy desktop environments or Ubuntu-whatever that a lot of guides seem geared towards.

I'm trying to switch to a bluetooth keyboard.  I have it so that when I run this it works:

```
$ hidd --connect <address>
```

The first issue is I can't really type this when the system boots and `xdm` starts.  (Sure I could solve that with an init script, but the next issue comes into play...) The other issue is that if I lose pairing (say the thing goes into power-saving mode), I need to re-run the above command.

How do I get it so that it pairs and re-pairs without any intervention?  On Windows with the same hardware I can pull out the keyboard randomly, type a key to wake it up, and it just pairs.  Then it goes to sleep, no big deal, it comes back on and is paired.  What do I need to get this behavior on Linux?  A lot of stuff steers towards `bluez-simple-agent` but even when I get that working it still needs manual setup and running `hidd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was weird.  Looking into what people said about `hidd` online, I tried using the `-i` option, I found that one of the daemons started by `/etc/init.d/bluetooth` was hogging the socket that `hidd --server` might have otherwise used.  Specifically I got:

```
# hidd -i hci0 --server
Can't listen on HID control channel: Address already in use
```

So strangely the following in `/etc/rc.local` does mostly what I wanted so far:

```
/etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
hidd -i hci0 --server
```

Kind of a crazy hack and I might prefer some other solution...